# Where can I put a CSS file in mean.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, mean

When i saw source code sample in meanjs, I can't find how to include file css in application. You can explain operation to manage and include css file. How do i can include file css seamlessly. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server make the folder 'public' ( which includes your css files) to public by adding:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a css file inside public folder. i have my css file in styles folder inside public.Inside  app/views/layout.server.view.html you have to load your css file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

Comment: Thank you but maybe i don't explain cleary , because method you point is brute way, i need to know operate automatically , standard method in meanjs, not manual method .

Comment: Then you can define it inside all.js and you can see asstes/css there you can define it